# How do I find the smallest number than can be divided by all numbers 1:n with no remainder?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have been trying to solve problem number 5 on Project Euler which goes like

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
>
> What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

I decided to go a step further and I decided I'd make it find the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to **limit** where **limit** is user-defined.

Problem starts when I execute my program, it immediately prints out 0. I tried tracing my code but that didn't work out.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

bool isRemainderFree(int num, int limit){
    bool bIsRemainderFree = true;
    if(num < limit){
        bIsRemainderFree = false;
    }else{
        for(int i=1; i <= limit; i++){
        if(num % i != 0){
            bIsRemainderFree = false;
            break;
        }
      }
    }
    return bIsRemainderFree;
}

int smallestMultiple(int limit){
    int smallestNum = 10;
    for(int i=1; i <= limit; i++){
        bool bFree = isRemainderFree(i, 10);
        if(bFree){
            cout << i << " is divisible by all numbers from 1 to " << limit << ".\n";
            smallestNum = i;
            return smallestNum;
            break;
        }
    }

}

int main(){
    int limit;
    cin >> limit;
    int smallestNum = smallestMultiple(limit);
    cout << smallestNum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: @user0042 I thought it seemed right and should run as intended, but I am obviously wrong. I have doubts around the smallestMultiple function though. I think the isRemainderFree function is OK.

Comment: I think you have to initialize your `limit` in `main()`. Like something low for testing, then 20 to solve the problem.

Comment: @arbuthnott I just did that, nothing changed.

Comment: Your for loop in `smallestMultiple` is only checking up to `limit`, ie checking if anything from 1 to 10 has no remainder when divided by every number from 1 to 10. You need to increase that limit size (for ex, above 2520 for 10). The 10 you pass into `isRemainderFree` represents the divisors, so you will not lose that letting `i` range higher.

Comment: @arbuthnott okay that definitely fixed it, I added another `upperBound` variable to replace the `limit`one in that for loop and assigned big values to it and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer should be simply the LCM of all numbers, it can be easily done in the following way

```
int gcd(int a, int b){
    if(b==0)
        return a;
    return gcd(b, a%b);
}
int main() {
    int limit = 10, lcm = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<=limit; i++){
        lcm = (lcm * i)/gcd(lcm,i);
    }
    printf("%d\n", lcm); // prints 2520
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**PYTHON CODE**

```
import math
   
# Returns the lcm of first n numbers
def lcm(n):
    ans = 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        ans = int((ans * i)/math.gcd(ans, i))        
    return ans
   
# main
n = 20
print (lcm(n))
```